# Comparar se variável é numero dentro de um if

Tags: javascript, variáveis, números

Tendo

```
var chute = Math.round(parseInt(prompt("Adivinhe em qual número estou pensando")));
var numeroPensado = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

if(chute != numeroPensado){
    document.write("Que pena, você errou, o número em que eu pensei era " + numeroPensado);
}else if(chute == numeroPensado){
    document.write("Parabéns, você acertou !");
}else{
    document.write("Ops! Devido a algum erro, não pude receber seus dados, certifique-se de colocar números, de preferência, inteiros")
}
```

Se o usuário digita um texto, ele entra na primeira condição, porém queria que ele entrasse no `else`. tentei usar algo como `chute = typeof 1` dentro do `if`, porém não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só isso resolve:

```
var chute = Math.round(parseInt(prompt("Adivinhe em qual número estou pensando")));
var numeroPensado = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

if(chute != numeroPensado && !isNaN(chute)){
    document.write("Que pena, você errou, o número em que eu pensei era " + numeroPensado);
}else if(chute == numeroPensado && !isNaN(chute)){
    document.write("Parabéns, você acertou !");
}else{
    document.write("Ops! Devido a algum erro, não pude receber seus dados, certifique-se de colocar números, de preferência, inteiros")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função isNaN do Javascript:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

```
isNaN(123) //false
isNaN(-1.23) //false
isNaN(5-2) //false
isNaN(0) //false
isNaN('123') //false
isNaN('Hello') //true
isNaN('2005/12/12') //true
isNaN('') //false
isNaN(true) //false
isNaN(undefined) //true
isNaN('NaN') //true
isNaN(NaN) //true
isNaN(0 / 0) //true
```

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, um `if` que testa se algo é igual e tem um `else if` se é diferente, não tem como existir uma terceira opção, ou é igual ou é diferente, então o `else` nunca seria executado. De qualquer forma é bom separar o que é validação de entrada de dados e o que é decisão de "negócio".

Segundo, para verificar se algo digitado é um número tem que fazer isso verificando explicitamente, com [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN):

```
var chute = Math.round(parseInt(prompt("Adivinhe em qual número estou pensando")));
if (!isNaN(chute)) document.write("Ops! Devido a algum erro, não pude receber seus dados, certifique-se de colocar números, de preferência, inteiros")
var numeroPensado = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
if (chute != numeroPensado) document.write("Que pena, você errou, o número em que eu pensei era " + numeroPensado);
else document.write("Parabéns, você acertou !");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Operators/CompareNumber.js).

Comment: Agora aparecem as duas mensagens

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido do operador de negação. De qualquer forma o correto é sair desse código se digitou algo errado, mas não sei como resolver sem ver o contexto geral, pode ser `break` ou um `return`, eventualmente pode ser alguma outra coisa.

Answer (score 1):

```
var chute = Math.round(parseInt(prompt("Adivinhe em qual número estou pensando")));
var numeroPensado = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

if(chute != numeroPensado && !isNaN(chute)){
    document.write("Que pena, você errou, o número em que eu pensei era " + numeroPensado);
}else if(chute == numeroPensado){
    document.write("Parabéns, você acertou !");
}else{
    document.write("Ops! Devido a algum erro, não pude receber seus dados, certifique-se de colocar números, de preferência, inteiros")
}
```

Verifica se Não é um Número. **N**ot **a** **N**umber.

```
isNan()
```